# Having to know the structure offset in which a function pointer is declared

Tags: c, function, memory-management, struct, function-pointers

Is there any way I can call a function (somewhere initialized) like that:

```
mystruct.foo();
```

allowing `foo()` to access the `mystruct` structure from the inside.

---

My goal is to use a bit of object oriented programming in C
and allow `foo` to access members, part of the `mystruct` structure.

Comment: Your question is very unclear! Please ask a specific question, you can to that. But please show the structure definition. And If what you are looking for is to hace access to the structure inside `foo` then please make that clear.

Comment: There's an [entire book](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf) on object oriented programming in C. It's not about clever syntax hacks, but a certain mental structure.

Comment: `offsetof` in `<stddef.h>`

Comment: @iharob well yes. How do I make it clearer ? You obviously understood it.

Comment: I was guessing because that made sense but in no way it was clear, now it's better though.

Comment: Well I am not a native speaker and I can't just know whether something is (un)clear to others.. but I am editing until it becomes clear.
Now that is better.. downvotes remain the same so...

Comment: @Malina If you *really* want to use object oriented programming in C, why not use C++, Objective-C, or other C-based language that supports it?

Comment: @KerrekSB okay, is it better now ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733427/spicing-c-with-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make it happen magically, the only thing I can think of is to do this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DECLARE_CLASS_METHOD(class, name, ...) \
    (*name)(class *this, __VA_ARGS__)

typedef struct Class Class;
struct Class
{
    int DECLARE_CLASS_METHOD(Class, method, int value);
};

int
method(Class *this, int value)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%p: %d\n", (void *) this, value);
    return 0;
}

int
main(void)
{
    Class instance;

    instance.method = method;
    instance.method(&instance, 9);

    return 0;
}
```

But as you can see you **must** pass the instance to the method, it will not happen automatically like in a OO language like c++.

Comment: ahh then I better not use it all.

Comment: @Malina Well yes! Either use the appropriate programming language or use the language as it's meant to be used. Don't try to force the language to behave like another language.